# How do I make python print a right arrow in hashes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want python to print me hashes in this order:

1. row = `#`
2. row = `##`
3. row = `###`
4. row = `####`

Then down, so:

5. row = `###`
6. row = `##`
7. row = `#`

I've managed to do the first 4 rows with the following code:

```
c = ("#")
n = 0
row = (c * 4 + "\n")

for c in row:
  n = n + 1 
  print(c * n)
```

Here is my expected output:

```
#
##
###
####
###
##
#
```

Here is the actual output:

```
#
##
###
####
```

Comment: Why have you written `c = ("#")`? Why not just write `c = "#"`? Are you looking to create a tuple containing a single hash? If so, you're supposed to add a comma at the end of the last quote, like this: `c = ("#",)`.

Comment: I just made a mistake. Thanx for noticing.

Answer (score 5):

With ONE loop

```
for i in range (-3, 4): print('#'*(4-abs(i)))
```

If you want to generalize

```
nmax = int(input('Max number of hash marks? '))
for i in range (1-nmax, nmax): print('#'*(nmax-abs(i)))
```

Comment: A smile came to my face when I saw that you only used **one** `range`! You've earned my respect.

Comment: `abs(i)` is absolutely beautiful here. pun intended.

Comment: i was hoping for more mathematical solution, and you gave it to me. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop with the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#range) function:

```
for i in range(1, 8):
  print("#" * i)
```

Then repeat the same using the [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#reversed) function:

```
for i in reversed(range(1, 8)):
  print("#" * i)
```

You could also use a single loop, like this:

```
for i in (list(range(1, 8)) + list(range(1, 8))[::-1]):
  print("#" * i)
```

Either way, the first two loops combined and the third loop would output:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
######
#####
####
###
##
#
```

**NOTE:** writing `list(range(1, 8))` is the same as writing `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`.

Good luck.

Comment: Not sure defining a tuple to iterate on is a good practive, you are allocating memory for nothing. As a side note, the `start_step` of range is 0 by default :)

Comment: @BlueSheepToken Thanks for the warning, but that's not a tuple, it's a pair of parenthesis wrapped around a list concatenation.

Comment: correct ! My bad. It is still allocating memory though ^^

Comment: As a side note, writing `range(1, 8)` is not the same as writing `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. Range returns a range object, list returns a list object. Range is not allocating memory in python 3 (as the user is asking)